# Problem sending data to a web server using W5100 shield

Tags: php, html, webserver, ethernet

I'm trying to send data to a Web Server using my W5100 shield with Arduino. But for some reason I'm getting this problem when I try to send, It seems like an HTTP Error. I'm editing so you can see my Arduino code too, maybe it helps. I hope I will be able to send this data, I tried changing HTTP/1.0 to HTTP/1.1 but had no success.

The problem:

```
Connected to network, your ip: 192.168.100.00 


Connecting to the server and sending data:
Sensor 1 = 7.00
Sensor 2 = 9.00
Sensor 3 = 89.00


HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 16 Oct 2019 18:47:20 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://mywebsite.com.br/conexao.php?s1=7.00&s2=9.00&s3=89.00
Content-Length: 317
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://mywebsite/conexao.php?s1=7.00&amp;s2=9.00&amp;s3=89.00">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache Server at mywebsite.com.br Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

This is the Arduino code

```
 if (ArduinoClient.available())
  {
    char dadosretornados = ArduinoClient.read();
    Serial.print(dadosretornados);
  }
  if (!ArduinoClient.connected())
  {
    ArduinoClient.stop();
  }

  char comando = Serial.read();

  if (comando == '1')
  {
    //====================================================== ENFEITE ============================================================================================================
    Serial.println("\n");
    Serial.println("Conectando ao servidor e enviando dados: ");
    delay(500); //Delay apenas de enfeite
    Serial.print("Sensor 1 = ");
    Serial.println(sensor1);
    Serial.print("Sensor 2 = ");
    Serial.println(sensor2);
    Serial.print("Sensor 3 = ");
    Serial.println(sensor3);
    delay(1000); //Delay apenas de enfeite
    Serial.println("\n");
    //===========================================================================================================================================================================

    if (ArduinoClient.connect(servidor, 80))
    {
      //Sucesso ao conectar
      //ArduinoClient.println("GET /conexao.php HTTP/1.0");   // Podemos trocar para HTTP/1.1 se der algum problema
      ArduinoClient.print("GET /conexao.php?");
      ArduinoClient.print("s1=");
      ArduinoClient.print(sensor1);
      ArduinoClient.print("&s2=");
      ArduinoClient.print(sensor2);
      ArduinoClient.print("&s3=");
      ArduinoClient.print(sensor3);
      ArduinoClient.println(" HTTP/1.0");

      ArduinoClient.println("Host: mywebsite.com.br"); 
      ArduinoClient.println("Connection: close"); 
      ArduinoClient.println();         
    }
    else 
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your site is redirecting to https://. Don’t waste your time as Arduino doesn’t have enough processing power and memory to process complex SSL requests. I already wasted my many nights. Post to http:// or use ESP which has required libraries to processs https:// requests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).